# Is sip api in Android 2.3 support the re-invite request and SDP media negotiation?

Tags: sip, sdp

It seems that sip api in android 2.3 does not support the re-invite request and SDP media negotiation, what  should I do?  Do you nice guys have any recommendation of sip stack for Android?

Answer (score 1):

[csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) is a popular SIP softphone for Android. It's built on top of the [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) stack so that could be an option for you.

Do you definitely need to use re-INVITEs? Generally with most SIP providers you can get by without them. It means you may lose the ability to do things like music on hold but for vanilla calling re-INVITEs aren't really necessary.